# How to implement countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count: for class that internally use NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsfastenumeration

I wanted to use

```
 for (TBL_CardView *cardView in cardsInHand)
    {
        // <#statements#>
    }
```

TBL_CardView is my custom class, and `cardsInHand` is just `(TBL_CardViewArray*)`

So I need to implement `countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:` for my `TBL_CardViewArray` class.
Is this correct ?

This is my TBL_CardViewArray.h

```
/**
 *    Keep TBL_CardView in array
 */
@interface TBL_CardViewArray : NSObject

- (TBL_CardView *)drawCard;
- (void)addCard:(TBL_CardView *)card;
- (NSUInteger)cardsRemaining;
- (NSArray*) cardViewArray;

- (TBL_CardView *)drawRandomCard;

@end
```

Some important part from TBL_CardViewArray.m

```
@implementation TBL_CardViewArray
{
    NSMutableArray *_cards;
}
```

So I am just using `TBL_CardViewArray`as s wrapper around NSMutableArray for storing my `TBL_CardView`class.

**Question**
How to implement countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count: for my `TBL_CardViewArray` class.

I did google it, but not found some example that I could reuse easy.
My assumption is that because I am already using NSMutableArray for storing that it is not so complicated, but I can not figure it how ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quite simply, forward it to the underlaying `NSMutableArray`:

```
- (NSUInteger)countByEnumeratingWithState:(NSFastEnumerationState *)state objects:(id __unsafe_unretained [])stackbuf count:(NSUInteger)len {
    return [_cards countByEnumeratingWithState:state objects:stackbuf count:len];
}
```

You have to avoid mutating the array while it's being enumerated.

Comment: when I add this to my m file I got  `Must explicitly describe intended ownership of an object array parameter`

Comment: So I have change it to `- (NSUInteger)countByEnumeratingWithState:(NSFastEnumerationState *)state objects:(__unsafe_unretained id [])stackbuf count:(NSUInteger)len`is this valid ?

Comment: Apple doc is always up to date.

Comment: It's not, but headers are.